# How is the total mass of Andromeda determined?

Tags: mass, galaxies

I am currently attempting to use Doppler shifts on both the advancing and receding sides of the galaxy to determine the mass. I am not sure exactly how I would convert the advancement and recession velocities to tangential velocities, which I need to determine the mass contained within the galaxy.

Also, how would I account for the dark matter halo? As far as I understand, the Doppler shift method only works for the farthest visible sides of the galaxy.

Comment: This paper might be useful: ["The Masses of the Milky Way and Andromeda Galaxies"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.4565)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to worry about any spherically symmetric distribution of matter, dark or otherwise, that lies outside the radii you have measurements for. It has no effect (see the shell theorem).

Your velocities tell you something about the mass *interior* to your velocity measurements.

Unless you have lots of measurements as a function of radius, there's not much you can do without making simplifying assumptions. I'll assume you don't.

In which case what you could do is take two measurements on opposite sides and take half the difference as the velocity at their average radius. You need to correct this by dividing by the sine of the estimated inclination of the disc to the line of sight (where 90 degrees would be seeing the disc "edge on"). You also need to correct your measurement by dividing by the sine of an azimuth angle of the location of your velocity measurement in the disc (where 90 or 270 degrees would be an object at the Galaxy "limb").

Then, assuming that the mass interior to your radius, $M_r$ is either symmetrically distributed or centrally concentrated, you can use the shell theorem again to argue that
$$\frac{v^2}{r} = \frac{GM_r}{r^2}$$

NB. This approximation may be quite poor if a large fraction of the mass is in a disk.

If this is too simple a treatment, then you need to indicate exactly what data you have and what way you wish to model the mass distribution.